# How do I migrate 1000+ nodes iteratively with term hierarchy and links in a CSV file?

Tags: 9, migrations

I run for almost 15 years now a Drupal website as a hobby. I had lots of help of the great Drupal commmunity with this. And was able to migrate from drupal 5-6-7 with the modules which were add hand. Now I need to go to Drupal 10. But how?

My site is fully dependent on the weblinks module, and there is no Drupal 10 version of this. I have 1000+ nodes on it.

My thoughts are to migrate the content through migrate modules to Drupal 10 native Link.
So converting Weblinks to Link.
And next to this I have term-lineage in the site. City-Region-Country. Location data and Address info

I was able to get the data out of Drupal 7 site and blogged about it here:
https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/upgrading-drupal/2023-03-09/how-did-i-export-data-drupal-7-without-using-migrate-and-how-to-get-this-into-drupal-10

I share a link to the Weblinks Node form made with csvtoyaml software online here:
https://martijnhaan.nl/?p=6901&preview=true

Is somebody able to share a migration process like this?
May be only the term-hierarchy?

Can you fill a Drupal 10 Node/Entity iteratively with Migrate modules from a csv file?
So first fill the Node title, body
Then the term hierarchy
Then the Link info
Then the Address info

This way there should not have to be build very complex Migration script, every time a different alteration of the script to fill other fields in the same nodes? Is this possible?

Comment: The link to the Weblinks Node form is broken.  Could you show the structure of the data you are trying to migrate?  In addition to Migrate, Feeds module can also handle CSVs, especially the case in which you need to repeatedly update the same nodes with new values.

Comment: Hi, Does this link work: https://martijnhaan.nl/geen-categorie/yaml-version-of-node ? Greetings,